# Retrieve names of called functions in a C program (Lib ELF)

Tags: c, elf

I'm trying to get the name of the called functions in a C program.

For exemple, this is my code:

```
void toto(void)
{
    printf("toto\n");
}

void tutu(void)
{
    printf("tutu\n");
}

void mdr(void)
{
    printf("tutu\n");
    printf("tutu\n");
    printf("tutu\n");
    printf("tutu\n");
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    toto();
    tutu();
    mdr();
}
```

I only wanna have on results : Main(), toto(), tutu() and mdr().
But the problem is, that when i'm using the Libelf, i retrieve some informations on the Symbol Table, but it gives me my functions called and more, like this example :

```
...
    57: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
    58: 0000000000401148    47 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 mdr
    59: 0000000000401126    17 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 toto
    60: 0000000000404020     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __data_start
    61: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    62: 0000000000402008     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    15 __dso_handle
    63: 0000000000401137    17 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 tutu
    64: 0000000000402000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _IO_stdin_used
    65: 00000000004011a0   101 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_init
    66: 0000000000404028     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _end
    67: 0000000000401070     5 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN    13 _dl_relocate_static_pie
    68: 0000000000401040    47 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _start
    69: 0000000000404024     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 __bss_start
    70: 0000000000401177    37 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
    71: 0000000000404028     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    23 __TMC_END__
    72: 0000000000401000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN    11 _init
```

So how can i only retrieve my called functions ? Thanks again for the help

Comment: Your code correctly prints the names of the functions in the order they are called. The libelf listing are the names of functions and object in the executable; it doesn't tell you the order in which they are called. What do you want?

Comment: To retrieve only functions that i called, like Main(), toto(), tutu() and mdr(). @PaulOgilvie

Comment: Retrieve from what?

Comment: To retrieve it with the ELF Lib, i don't know if this is possible.. (And by the way, the functions are not called in the order, see it, i normally call main firstly, and toto, tutu, and for finish, mdr. But it print me mdr, toto, tutu and main, so i don't understand too how can i print them with the good order, but this is a differant problem.) @PaulOgilvie

Comment: I am sorry, I just don't understand what you want.

Comment: I actually retrieve the second code prog posted, but i only want to have a prog, who can retrieve from the ELF Library, the called function in my C prog, created by me. But i wanna have this, in this order: main() -> toto() -> printf() -> tutu() -> printf() -> mdr -> printf() -> printf() -> printf() -> printf() -> end of the prog. I hope this is possible! @PaulOgilvie

Comment: Do you want to write some decompiler?

Comment: Among others .. @Mathieu

Comment: are you looking for a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Call-graph_profiler) ?

Comment: Filter the result above? `... | grep FUNC | grep -v _`